What is the best way to merge two dataframes that one of them has overlapping ranges?
My DataFrames are:
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [10, 12, 14, 20, 25, 30, 42, 50, 80]
    }
)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'start': [9, 19],
        'end': [26, 50],
        'label': ['a', 'b']
    }
)

Expected output: Adding column label to df_1:
a    label
10    a
12    a
14    a
20    a
25    a
20    b
25    b
30    b
42    b
50    b

df_2 defines the ranges of labels. So for example, the first row of df_2 start of the range is 9 and the end is 22. Now I want to slice df_1 based on start and end and give this label to the slice. Note that start is exlusive and end is inclusive. And my labels ranges are overlapping.
These are my attempts. The first one works but I am not sure if it is the best.
# attempt_1
dfc = pd.DataFrame([])
for idx, row in df_2.iterrows():
    start = row['start']
    end = row['end']
    label = row['label']
    df_slice = df_1.loc[df_1.a.between(start, end, inclusive='right')]
    df_slice['label'] = label
    dfc = pd.concat([df_slice, dfc], ignore_index=True)

## attempt 2
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_2['start'], df_2['end'], closed='both')
label = df_2.iloc[idx.get_indexer(df_1.a), 'label']
df_1['label'] = label.to_numpy()


Your approach is a Cartesian/cross join, which is fine for small sizes, but expensive as data size grows. The use of iterrows doesn't make things better either. A better, faster approach is to use binary search. Your start and end columns are both monotonically sorted - a binary search fits here perfectly and will be good both memory and performance wise

I'd try to concatenate generated labeled ranges using pandas.concat this way:
template = df_1.set_index('a')
ranges = df_2.values

output = pd.concat(
    template.loc[start:end].assign(label=label) 
    for start, end, label in ranges
).reset_index()

It's close to your solution with two major differences:

All iterations are collapsed into an inner generator.
We use df_1['a'] as an index, which is implied by its nature.


A native pandas way
You can use list comprehension with range and explode to create a dataframe to join df_1 on for the each element in df_2's start and end ranges.
df_2_join = df_2.assign(
                 a=[range(s, e + 1) for s, e in zip(df_2["start"], df_2["end"])]
            ).explode("a")

df_1.merge(df_2_join).sort_values('start')

Output:
    a  start  end label
0  10      9   26     a
1  12      9   26     a
2  14      9   26     a
3  20      9   26     a
5  25      9   26     a
4  20     19   50     b
6  25     19   50     b
7  30     19   50     b
8  42     19   50     b
9  50     19   50     b


This is a form of Cartesian join which is fine for small sizes but gets expensive as the data size increases or the ranges increase

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [10, 12, 14, 20, 25, 30, 42, 50, 80]
    }
)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'start': [9, 19],
        'end': [26, 50],
        'label': ['a', 'b']
    }
)

# Convert columns to numpy arrays
a_values = df_1['a'].to_numpy()
start_values = df_2['start'].to_numpy()
end_values = df_2['end'].to_numpy()
labels = df_2['label'].to_numpy()

# Create a boolean matrix where each element (i, j) indicates whether 
# a_values[i] falls within the j-th range
m1 = (a_values[:, None] > start_values)
m2 = (a_values[:, None] <= end_values)
mask = (m1 & m2) 

# Find the indices where mask is True
rows, cols = np.where(mask)

# Create the new DataFrame with all valid (value, label) pairs
expanded_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': a_values[rows],
    'label': labels[cols]
})

print(expanded_df)
'''
    a label
0  10     a
1  12     a
2  14     a
3  20     a
4  20     b
5  25     a
6  25     b
7  30     b
8  42     b
9  50     b
'''

